# Facebook login button widget no resource identifer

Tags: android, facebook, android-resources

I have inherited some code and I'm working on it, however, when I try to build it I get the following issue:

```
activity_login.xml:26: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'login_text' in package
```

My button xml is as follows:

```
<com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
        xmlns:fb="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/facebookBtn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="facebookBtnClick"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        fb:login_text="@string/loginWithFacebook"
        />
```

I have also tried putting in `xmlns:fb="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.facebook.widget"`
but this didn't work for me either, if anyone has any suggestions I'd greatly appreciate it

Comment: Do you have the FacebookSDK project added as well?

Comment: I'm currently trying to add the newest one to the project 3.20.0

Comment: what's the path to your FacebookSDK? Seems our using a wrong path.

Comment: it's included in my libs file in my project, sorry I'm unsure as to what you mean

Comment: So it is a jar file?

Comment: no it's a folder, I just downloaded the newest version and there's no jar

Comment: Okey, that's fine. So you imported it as a project in Eclipse and then used it as a reference from your project?

Comment: @DJ-DOO It seams my answer helps, could you accept it as a right one?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can find info here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/upgrading-4.x

> Style attr tags are now namespaced to avoid conflicts. Apps will need
>   to add the namespace "com_facebook_" to their existing facebook sdk
>   style attrs.

So, use `fb:com_facebook_login_text` now.